# How to call Terragrunt HCL files from Terratest Go script?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, terragrunt, terratest

I have a terragrunt script which is working fine after running terragrunt apply-all command line but same thing i am **not able to do/invoke form Go script.** using **TgApplyAll** function

Below is my Go script
Working terragrunt script is kept in D:\vertica-terragrunt-US-286094-Modules\with-infra location and it is working fine with manual **terragrunt apply-all** command but from Go script i am getting error

[image]

Getting error as below

'''
github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform.TgInvalidBinary.Error(...)
c:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest@v0.30.15/modules/terraform/errors.go:12

Detailed error
func (err TgInvalidBinary) Error() string {
return fmt.Sprintf("terragrunt must be set as TerraformBinary to use this function. [ TerraformBinary : %s ]", err)
}
'''

I used same code which i used to call terraform code from terratest Go script for calling terragrunt code also but it is not working

Can anyone help me / direct me to location like how to invoke working terragrunt code from terratest Go script ?

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the text currently displayed in the image and remove it. [More on formatting posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: On a side note, have you really "set terragrunt as TerraformBinary to use that function" as the error message suggests?

Comment: @kostix  I am not getting how to set "set terragrunt as TerraformBinary" example code is not available for that anywhere ... So struggling hard...

Comment: A couple notes: 1. There's no such thing as a "go [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)". 2. [Don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: [This one](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/88422750-terragrunt-fails-to-copy-files-if-an-ssh-agent-is-running-on-my-system) looks like what you need. Also [this](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/so01nDZLnIQ/m/h50TyvKLAwAJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You need to set TerraformBinary  to terragrunt in the terraform options like this :

```
terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{

    TerraformDir: "D:/vertica-terragrunt-US-286094-Modules/with-infra",
    TerraformBinary : "terragrunt",
}
```

because the default binary is terraform and TgInvalidBinary occurs when a terragrunt function is called and the TerraformBinary is set to a value other than terragrunt.

here's a ref

https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#TgInvalidBinary

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/modules/terraform/cmd.go

Comment: Thank a lot Montassar Bouagina,  Its working fine now :)